# how to use try and catch to print out the unknown error message when calling a function in general in matlab

Tags: matlab, error-handling, try-catch

This is the code

```
try
    ** = myfunction( ~ );
catch e
    % how shall I do to print out the unknown message ?
end
```

I encounter this during a project. I already fixed the error. But I was still confused a bit without an answer. So I post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must decide how to handle the error in the catch. Do you want to simply print out the error message and continue on? If so:

```
try
    ** = myfunction( ~ );

catch e
    fprintf(1,'ERROR: %s\n', e.message);

end
```

Comment: is there a way to find out where is the error or what thing cause the error? For example, I got the error "ERROR: Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods." Is there a way to find out the object which causes the error ?

Comment: e is an *MException* class object It has a "stack" property. You could look at the "stack" property to determine what line of code the error originated from. For example: *e.stack*

Comment: @study: Have you looked at the documentation? Such things are described very well in Matlab's [online documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) for `try` (also `help try` and `doc try` right in your Command Window of course).

Comment: e.stack is a struct array with three fields: name, file and line. oh yeah ~